# Apache proxy auth

Tags: apache, proxy, prestashop-1.6, http-proxy

How do I authenticate **Apache** in proxy? Look that I'm not trying to make Apache a proxy.

My computer is behind a proxy that needs authentication. All application I run, needs to use user/pass to access internet.

How can I tell to Apache to use proxy auth?

Comment: OK, i found the function ProxyRemote, but this does not allow authentication. How can I do that?

Comment: So. As I was using curl in PHP to access the internet I user curl options to set proxy info.